# jQuery - append content on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, clone

I have 4 list items, first one as a featured box, and other 3 items have normal content.

when hover on one of these 3 boxes, i need to append item content itself to featured box.

note: featured box will append first item as default.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JL3c4/1/)

**code:**

```
<ul class="items clearfix">
    <li class="item">
        <a href=""><h2 class="title">01 - Lorem ipsum</h2></a>
        <p class="description">
            1-Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/42bdc2/FFFFFF&amp;text=News" alt="">
    </li><!-- Featured Item -->

    <li class="item">
        <a href=""><h2 class="title">01 - Lorem ipsum</h2></a>
        <p class="description">
            1-Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/42bdc2/FFFFFF&amp;text=News" alt="">
    </li><!-- End Item -->

    <li class="item">
        <a href=""><h2 class="title">02 - Lorem ipsum</h2></a>
        <p class="description">
            2-Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/42bdc2/FFFFFF&amp;text=News" alt="">
    </li><!-- End Item -->

    <li class="item">
        <a href=""><h2 class="title">03 - Lorem ipsum</h2></a>
        <p class="description">
            3-Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/42bdc2/FFFFFF&amp;text=News" alt="">
    </li><!-- End Item -->
</ul>
```

Comment: I see no attempt by you to solve your problem. Post the JavaScript you've tried. Also, do you want the content of the last three list items to be appended to the first list item, or replace the content of the first list item?

Comment: yes, replace the content of the first list item. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/IbrahimAboSeada/SYCqM/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed!!

demo: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bXx5j/)

**code:**

```
var feat =$(".item").first();

var item =$(".item").next();

item.mouseover(function(){
    featitem = $(this).html();
    feat.html(featitem);
    $(this).addClass("featured");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok my first post on this site.

How about this:

```
var feat =$(".item").first();

var item =$(".item").next();

    item.mouseover(function(){
        feat.find("a:first-child").before($(this).html());

    });
```

/*=================*/

//you can also add a conditional statement if you do not want to repeat content once it is 
 added to featured:

```
var feat =$(".item").first();

var item =$(".item").next();

item.mouseover(function(){

//if the post has the class featured do nothing
if($(this).hasClass("featured")){
    return;
}

//else append the featured box
else{         
    feat.find("a:first-child").before($(this).html());
    $(this).addClass("featured");
 }


});
```

/*=================*/

//or you can remove the item once the featured content is appended with the item's content

```
var feat =$(".item").first();

var item =$(".item").next();

item.mouseover(function(){
    feat.find("a:first-child").before($(this).html());
    $(this).closest("li").remove();
});
```

Comment: items are repeated on each hover, see [link](http://jsfiddle.net/IbrahimAboSeada/SYCqM/3/)
how i can prevent this repetition?

Comment: can you please check/update on jsfiddle? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/IbrahimAboSeada/SYCqM/3/)
I need to prevent repetition for featured content once hove on normal items, and do not remove items once i hover on it.

Comment: sorry, i did not understand your requirement. Did you just want to change the innerHTML of the featured content when you hover on the items?